# How to email specified cells in single row with Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a code within Google Sheets script in order to send an email containing the values from three cells (D2, H2, and L2).

I've got close with this code:

```
function sendCounts() {

//setup function
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("PART COUNTS");

var message = "";
{

//set current row
var CurrentRow = 2;

//set HTML template for information
message +=
"<p><b>First Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
"<p><b>Second Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
"<p><b>Third Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[12] + "</p><br><br>";

//set the row to look at
var setRow = CurrentRow;
}

//define who to send updates to 
var SendTo = "me@emailaddress.com";

//set subject line
 var Subject = "DAILY PART COUNTS";


//send the actual email  
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: SendTo,
cc: "",
subject: Subject,
htmlBody: message,
});
}
```

The email is sent in the correct format, but each of the three values appear as 'undefined' in the email body instead of the values of cells D2, H2, and L2.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- The reason of the error of `each of the three values appear as 'undefined' in the email body instead of the values of cells D2, H2, and L2` is `CurrentRow`. `CurrentRow` is a number. But in your script, you are using it as an array. This is the reason of the issue.

  - In order to avoid this issue, retrieve the values from the sheet of `PART COUNTS`.
- When the value from the row 2 of the sheet is retrieved, `CurrentRow` can be used as an array. But in this case, the array index starts `0`, and the indexes of "D", "H" and "L" are 3, 7 and 11.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var CurrentRow = 2;

//set HTML template for information
message +=
"<p><b>First Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
"<p><b>Second Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
"<p><b>Third Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[12] + "</p><br><br>";
```

To:

```
var CurrentRow = sh0.getRange("A2:L2").getValues()[0];

//set HTML template for information
message +=
"<p><b>First Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
"<p><b>Second Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
"<p><b>Third Count: </b>" + CurrentRow[11] + "</p><br><br>";
```

#### References:

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: You nailed it, that was very helpful and informative, thank you so much!

Comment: @J. Kubassek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.